# Regex to find magic numbers excluding comments for code written in C++

Tags: regex, ack

I'm trying to find magic numbers in a C++ codebase using `ack`.  In this case, my guess is that most magic numbers will be those not immediately preceded by a letter or an underscore.  That probably sounds broad, but I'd rather cast too wide a net.  I'd like to be able to exclude `[0]` and `[1]`, but that seems extra-tricky.  The numbers might be hex, so I'll have to account for that, too.  Here's what I was thinking:

```
ack '[^/][^/*].*[^A-Za-z_](0x)?(\d+)'
```

but that only highlights the last digit, and it also seems to capture commented lines.  Am I at least on the right track?

Answer (score 4):

I use a flexible regular expression with positive/negative lookarounds for this kind of task.

The general pattern I like to stick to is:

```
(?<=%PRECEEDED_BY%)(?<!%NOT_PRECEEDED_BY%)%MATCH%(?!%NOT_FOLLOWED_BY%)(?=%FOLLOWED_BY%)
```

Find a customised version for your use-case below.

```
(?<=[\W])(?<![\[A-Za-z_])\d+(?![\]])(?=[\W])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

The `\W` special character is shorthand for the character class `[^A-Za-z0-9_]`.
The `\d` special character is shorthand for the character class `[0-9]`.